# Node-Red: Pass data into stdin of exec instead of rerun

Tags: node.js, iot, node-red

I am a beginner to Node-Red.
I have successfully tried to use node red exec node to run a python ML script.
Now I am trying to input some parameters into the python file without stopping or rerunning the python script. 
How can I do that with Node-Red?

I tried to use the flow as shown below.
MQTT -> Exec node (call python script and appending parameters at the back.)
But this reruns the script each time when a new msg payload come in.

My ML python script is trying to get inputs from stdin. Is there any way to do this via passing it into stdin? I do not want to use MQTT subscribe in my python script.

Answer (score 1):

Use the daemon node instead of the exec node, this node is specifically for long running tasks

Comment: Thanks, that answered my question.

Comment: sorry to disturb again but i cannot seem to pass in the data. I tried to create a python command to read the input using raw_input and print out the input. but nothing is showing on my node-red output. the command i input in deamon is sudo. Arguments is python -u /home/pi/test/testing.py. Do you have a simple example to show me?

Comment: You cannot use sudo inthe exec or daemon nodes as it would be a privilege escalation (you should also not need it to just run ML code)

Comment: I have a simple python code now that read from stdin and print out the same message. How can i use node red to implement this if i want my code to keep running and reading from stdin instead of rerunning? An example will help.

Comment: That's what the original answer is, the daemon node. If you still have problems ask a new question and include the code you've tried and somebody will help you fix it.